# What WCF security should I choose

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I'm new to WCF and got confused to choose security and authentication. Below are my requirements

1. I'm going to publish my service on internet.
2. I should get only user id and password from the client consuming the service. There should not be any need to install some certificate at client end.
3. The service should be secured with SSL certification.
4. It will be great if the message is gonna to be encrypted or secured.
5. I need to implement this before EOD tomorrow.

Please help me in choosing and implementing authentication & security. Below are the things I need

1. Which security & authentication should I choose .
2. How to implement it (sample code or reference links will help )
3. What should I do to make my service work in development environment, QA environment and production environment.

NOTE : SSL will be installed only in production env. I should self signed certificate in other env.

Comment: Point 5 doesn't sound healthy... WCF can take a while to get set up, tested etc...

Comment: I agree Nathan. No issues even if it delays but I need a good solution.